# How to set a serial port to RS-485 mode?

Tags: serial-port

I am using a converter from serial port to usb and in Windows it is possible to open Serial port properties and set a checkbox RS-485, only after that I am able to receive data from the device. How to do the same in Linux? Because by default I am getting the same result like in Windows with unchecked RS-485:

```
Port name - /dev/ttyACM0; Method name - readBytes(); Serial port operation timeout (500 ms).
execute try 2 error: I/O exception - failed to read
```

My device is:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04e2:1411 Exar Corp.

setserial -a /dev/ttyACM0
/dev/ttyACM0, Line 0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
        Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 5, divisor: 0
        closing_wait: 300
        Flags: spd_normal low_latency
```

Comment: OK. I solved that. In my particular case I am using a converter CC-USB-RS485-150U from EPSolar and I have to install a driver for USB from here https://www.exar.com/common/content/default.aspx?id=10296 but the problem was in the official driver and working copy of it is located here https://github.com/kasbert/epsolar-tracer/tree/master/xr_usb_serial_common-1a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write some C code, as described in the [kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt).

```
#include <linux/serial.h>
struct serial_rs485 rs485conf = {0};

int fd = open ("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0)...
rs485conf.flags |= SER_RS485_ENABLED;
if (ioctl (fd, TIOCSRS485, &rs485conf) < 0)...
```